# Exit brakeman on high confidence warnings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, brakeman

I found this on brakeman documentation:

`brakeman --exit-on-warn --exit-on-error`

Default is to exit on warning and error. How do I modify the above code to exit on HIGH confidence warnings only?

Answer (score 0):

You can report only high confidence warnings with `--confidence-level 2` or `-w2`.

There is currently no way to report all warnings but only set the exit code for high/medium warnings only. There is an [open feature request](https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman/issues/1479) for that functionality.